# The application I installed on Google Play does not work on android 5 version and android 6 version. What would be the reason?

Tags: android, sdk, google-play

The application I installed on Google Play does not work on android 5 version and android 6 version. What would be the reason ?"The application is closed." error is displayed on the screen. Application Google Play Store Link : [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.frtparlak.EnglishWordTest) 
         Gradle Code:

```
 android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.frtparlak.EnglishWordTest"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
```

Comment: There are a lot of reasons. Use Android Vitals - bugs to fix.

Answer (score 0):

( A guess since no stacktrace is attached )
While you define 'minSDKVersion 16' you are still allowed to use code in your application incompatible with e.G. sdk 16.
Your compiler warns you but if you ignore these warnings and dont handle them your app will crash on some devices.
To fix it you can use the linter or just review your warnings and or your crash report.

Comment: What is linter ?